# Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core in .net project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, telerik, aws-sdk

[My project is using Telerik reporting to generate reports. One of the reports has a picture box that is fetching the image from S3 bucket and showing on the report but now the picture is throwing below error:
Could not load file or assembly 'AWSSDK.Core, version=3.3.0.0 Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken= 885c28607f98e604 or one of its dependencies' The System cannot find file specified.

I have tried to upgrade the AWSSDK to latest version from NuGet Package, but the report is still targeting the version 3.3.0.0. Also tried to manually install the dependency/Add the reference but nothing happened.

Comment: Does your project depend on other libraries that also target AWSSDK.Core lib?

Comment: No there are no such libraries that are targeting AWSSDK.Core lib but some of the projects are using the same library.